# Excel Google API - Change transport mode

Tags: excel, vba, api, google-maps

I am using the following code in Excel to calculate the travel distance between various places. In this calculation it calculates the "driving" directions.

I am however also looking for the public transport directions. I've been puzzling how to change the code to change the travel mode (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview#TravelModes), but I cant get it to work. Does anybody have an idea how to incorporate this?

```
Function TRAVELTIME(origin, destination, apikey)

Dim strUrl As String
strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & origin & "&destination=" & destination & "&key=" & apikey
 
Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
With httpReq
     .Open "GET", strUrl, False
     .Send
End With
 
Dim response As String
response = httpReq.ResponseText
 
Dim parsed As Dictionary
Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
Dim seconds As Integer
 
Dim leg As Dictionary
 
For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
    seconds = seconds + leg("duration")("value")
Next leg
 
 
 
TRAVELTIME = seconds
```

Comment: Where exactly is your issue? The documentation says you need to append the following paramaters to your URL `&mode=transit` and you can also include an `departure_time` or `arrival_time` like `&mode=transit&departure_time=now`. Append it in the same way as you did for `origin` and `destination`. Give it a try. If you get stuck or errors please [edit] your question and add the code you have tried including what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks, really didn't think the sollution would be that straightforward. I was thinking way to complex. Thanks for you help Peh!